# nano editor on OS X - How to type M-U for undo?

Tags: nano

I am using nano 2.5.3 on OS X Yosemite, and I see commands at the bottom such as:

```bash
M-U Undo
M-E Redo
```

So far, I have not been able to figure out which key or keys that <kbd>M</kbd> is referring to. What would be <kbd>M</kbd> on OS X?

Comment: Indeed to do have an `Alt` key

Comment: Possibly helpful: [Mac OS X keyboard shortcuts for terminal](//superuser.com/q/124336) and [Command key as Meta key in OS X Terminal.app](/q/1856437)

Comment: Alt-U after two presses, types `¨`

Comment: I am starting to think that these default shortcuts are just not suited for OS X and that I should rebind the keys to something else.

Comment: The `Alt` key also works for me as the M key in M-U and M-E in Manjaro Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- There is no "UNDO" in OSX `GNU nano 2.0.6`.
- Meta (M-) symbol is the `Esc` key in OSX. E.g. to **cut** text with `M-T`, enter `Esc`+ `T`.

  The `Main nano help text` says:

  > Escape-key sequences are notated with the Meta (M-) symbol and can be entered using either the Esc, Alt, or Meta key depending on your keyboard setup.
- Display the help text with all key combinations while in `nano` by entering `ctrl`+`G`.

  *Hide the help text with the same key combination.*
- Useful for navigating quickly:

  - `ctrl`+ `Y` / `ctrl`+ `V` -> Go one screenful up / down
  - `Esc`+ `S` -> Enable soft line wrapping
  - `Esc`+ `M` -> Enable Mouse support
  - Go to a line number

    - `Esc`+ `N` -> Enable line numbering
    - `Esc`+ `_` -> go to a line

      *You'll have to type 3 keys for that: `Esc`+ `Shift` + `-`*
- FYI: In debian's `GNU nano 5.4`, enter `Esc`+`U` on an OSX keyboard to "UNDO".

Answer (score 80):

Meta (<kbd>M</kbd>) symbol is the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key in OSX.

To undo a change in nano, press <kbd>ESC</kbd> and then <kbd>U</kbd> (i.e. one after another, not together).

Note that UNDO is not supported in the default MacOS provided nano (V2.0.6) -- to get the latest version:

```bash
brew install homebrew/dupes/nano
```

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation to use ESC. Perhaps it's a lack of knowledge (perhaps not) but there was no way that I was going to think of tapping ESC when I see "M". Fwiw, I'm using macOS, but connecting via SSH to a Linux server.

Comment: homebrew/dupes/nano is now deprecated, to download nano just type `brew install nano`

Comment: After installation via `brew install nano` it's necessary to link the new version using `brew link nano`. Finally just type `nano --version` to verify the new version like `6.2` rather then the old `2.0.6`.

Comment: Does not work in monterey nano

Comment: @joseluisq after brew link I had to reopen terminal to get new version.

Answer (score 1):

This question is old, but I think the correct answer is confusing in 2023 so I'm writing this update to help those who have the same issue.

First, install the latest nano version:

`brew install nano`

After installation is done, open a new terminal to be able to use the newly installed version and open nano.

Now you can use the following keys <kbd>esc</kbd> then <kbd>U</kbd> one after another (Not together).